# Handle file upload in RFC 6902 Json Patch

Tags: java, rest, angular, spring-boot, json-patch

I'm working on a application in which users can update their information. For the moment, `RFC 6902 Json-patch` is used to update *textual* information (firstname, lastname, phone...) via a basic HTML Form.

User can now add images to their profile. Is there any way to use `Json-patch` to perform multipart operations ?

---

**Note :** The images are stored in a file system. So in the client side, only the image path is given and it can be updated only after the form submission. My dto is as below :

```
public class ProfileDto {

    private Integer id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String defaultMedia; // <-- image path
    ...
}
```

**Solution to which I think :**

Since `defaultMedia` is of type String, `Json-patch` can be used to update the image path. The idea is when the form is submitted, perform a `Multipart POST` request to upload the image and get its URL. Then set `defaultMedia` of my `DTO` to the new URL.

This solution can create unsued images in the case when a error happened server side on form submission. So I need to add something to clean the file system.

Is there any easier solution to meet my needs ?

---

I'm using :

- Spring Boot : **1.5.1**
- Angular 2 : **2.4.5**

Comment: is anything update or solution yourselves?